# Bundle Cart Price Rule problem

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, magento2.3.5-p2

I'm essentially trying to create a multi-pack listing where the customer can choose their colour options of up to 4 items and assign a discount using a cart price rule.

I've set up the cart price rule so that when a customer has 2 of the simple products in their basket they receive 5% off, have 3 in the basket receive 10% off and have 4 in the basket receive 15% off.

Now, these discounts work fine on the single products but when trying to have them work them for my bundled item I would expect that when a customer adds 1 of each colour the discount would be applied however it seems as though the system is treating the bundle product as a single item so in order for the discount to apply I have to add 2 more bundles.

Anyone had this same issue in the past and found a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you duplicate the existing rule and set the conditions to match/ point to the children products only. The attributes present on the children products would have a ***(Children Only)*** next to the attribute name:

[image]